# Alfresco: how to setup user home at FTP

Tags: alfresco

Since I didn't get any answers on this question at Alfresco forum, I am trying here:

I would like to configure Alfresco, so that once user connects by FTP (or webdav) she is taken to the personal home space folder and she can't browse any other content beside of the personal folder.

I installed Alfresco 3.4d on Windows using the standard setup.
FTP server is configured out of the box, however the problem is 
that once user connects by FTP she is taken to the common root folder of entire ALfresco system, and from there the user can browse any content of any folder.

I tried to edit file-servers-context.xml and replace

```
  <property name="rootPath">
      <value>/${spaces.company_home.childname}
by
  <property name="rootPath">
      <value>/${spaces.company_home.childname}/${spaces.user_homes.childname}
```

but it apparently changes nothing.

Original post at Alfresco forum is: http://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=35864

Comment: I am start getting some replies at Alfresco forum.

Answer (score 1):

Finally it seems there is a good reply in the Alfresco forums, at least it served to me

http://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=35864#p116585